# java IRC client file transfer

Tags: java, networking

i'm stuck with a small problem that i can't solve .... i need to create an app in java that connects to irc server and have the ability to transfer a file to another client with in a specific channel. So i tried this below code and it doesnt work out,my problem is in making the socket to transfer the file. and at this given code i make the irc client to send you a file when you send a message "sendFile" to it, but it doesnt send the file named "any.txt" to the sender of the message. so what can i possibly do to transfer the file to the other client ??? .... and almost forgot ... when you try to send the command "sendFile" to the irc client, you must have a nickname "mer" without the "".

```
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.net.InetAddress;


       public class MainTest {

            private static String nickUse;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        // The server to connect to and our details.
    File fileIn = new File("any.txt");
    String server = "localhost";
    String nick = "testJava";
    String login = "anyName";

    // The channel which the bot will join.
    String channel = "#here";

    // Connect directly to the IRC server.
    ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(0);
    Socket socket = new Socket(server, 6667);
    InetAddress intetAdd = socket.getInetAddress();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream( )));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream( )));

    // Log on to the server.
    writer.write("NICK " + nick + "\r\n");
    writer.write("USER " + login + " 8 * : This is a channel\r\n");
    writer.flush( );

    // Read lines from the server until it tells us we have connected.
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
        if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
            // We are now logged in.
            break;
        }
        else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Nickname is already in use.");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Join the channel.
    writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");
    writer.flush( );


    // Keep reading lines from the server.
     while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
        if (line.startsWith("PING ")) {
            // We must respond to PINGs to avoid being disconnected.
            writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println("THis is the line recieved when server sends a ping verification "+line);
        }
        else {
            // Print the raw line received by the bot.
            System.out.println(line);
            if(line.contains(":") && line.contains("!")){
            int positionOfIni = line.indexOf(":");
            int lastOf = line.indexOf("!");
            String nickComm = line.substring(positionOfIni+1,lastOf);
                if(!nickComm.equalsIgnoreCase("mer")){
                    nickUse = nickComm;
                }
            }
            if(nickUse!=null && line.endsWith(nickUse) == false){
            int messagePo = line.lastIndexOf(":");
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n",nickUse,"Says:",line.substring(messagePo+1));
            nickUse = null;
            }
            if(line.endsWith("sendFile")){
                byte[] add = intetAdd.getAddress();
                writer.write("PRIVMSG " + "mer" +" :\u0001"+ "DCC SEND "+fileIn.getName()+" "+ipToLong(add)+" "+serverSoc.getLocalPort()+" "+fileIn.length()+"\u0001");
                writer.flush();

                Socket serSoc = serverSoc.accept();
                serSoc.setSoTimeout(30000);

                serverSoc.close();

                BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(serSoc.getOutputStream());
                BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(serSoc.getInputStream());
                BufferedInputStream finput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileIn));


                byte[] outBuffer = new byte[1024];
                byte[] inBuffer = new byte[4];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = finput.read(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length)) != -1) {
                    output.write(outBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    output.flush();
                    input.read(inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.length);
                    Thread.sleep(4);
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}
public static long ipToLong(byte[] address) {
    if (address.length != 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("byte array must be of length 4");
    }
    long ipNum = 0;
    long multiplier = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        int byteVal = (address[i] + 256) % 256;
        ipNum += byteVal*multiplier;
        multiplier *= 256;
    }
    System.out.println(ipNum);
    return ipNum;
    }
  }
```

Comment: "doesnt work out" is not a problem description. Please punctutate and capitalize this incomprehensible mess.

Comment: hey EJP, i just did some changes in the question .... but i think the question is clear. i just want to send the file to the other client.

Comment: @EJP hey EJP, i just did some changes in the question .... but i think the question is clear. i just want to send the file to the other client.

Comment: Is "mer" the nick of the bot or the other client. In case its the bots nick I think you need to send the PRIVMSG to the nick of the requester.

Comment: the nick "mer" is the name of the requester. you must pretend to be "mer" when trying to write the command "sendFile".

Answer (score 0):

i just conclude the answer of having not to transfer with the help of IRC server. but instead i just create it's own server, that is capable of receiving files (Encrypted).